# WPF fixing fuzzy DataPicker text boxes that have drop shadows

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF form that has TextBoxes and DatePickers.  The DatePicker text boxes fonts are really fuzzy because of a drop shadow effect I put on the style.  Initially all the controls had an explicit drop shadow effect as part of the style, but I fixed this by removing the drop shadow effect from the controls and moved it to Rectangles with the same drop shadow.

Then I place the Rectangle directly behind the textboxes - I still have the visual effect and the fonts in the overlaying controls looked great.

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="dropShadow" Color="Gray" Opacity=".50" ShadowDepth="8" />

<Style x:Key="BackingRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
  <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropShadow}" />
</Style>

<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource BackingRectangleStyle}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" ... />
```

However, I have the same problem with foggy fonts with DatePicker TextBoxes since the drop shadow effect is still directly on the control.

[image]

I do not have a DatePicker style, but I do have a style of the DatePickerTextBox, which is where the effect comes from.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource dropShadow}" />
</Style>
```

What I don't know how to do is to follow my previous pattern of removing the effect, creating a Rectangle with the same effect and placing it behind the DatePicker TextBox so it's the same size, etc.  I need a little help on the XAML to do so.

Can anyone provide me any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `SnapsToDevicePixels` in the `DatePickerTextBox` style, e.g: `<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />`

Comment: Since this is text, I would look at modifying the ClearType properties of the text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749295.aspx

Comment: Both of these suggestions (SnapsToDevicePixels and RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint) did not change anything.  I have a solution, I just don't know how to set it up in XAML.

Comment: [This guy has the Style for the DatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1125840/1993545)

Answer (score 0):

Because knowlege about TextFormattingMode really needs spreading, I decided to post the following - even though it strangely doesn't help with the `DatePickerTextBox`, which is still fuzzy. It prevents you from the stunt you pulled with the rectangle behind the `TextBox` though.

[image] [image]

Unless you have large, or transformed text, always use `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` in your outermost WPF container.
This was introduced in WPF 4.0, and I suppose the default "Ideal" reflects earlier versions, but what a mind-boggling mistake that is...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" x:Name="MyWindow" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Height="300" Width="400"
            TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"> <!-- Please notice the effect of this on font fuzzyness -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Key="DropShadow" Color="Gray" Opacity=".5" ShadowDepth="8"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="Really Sharp" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Effect="{StaticResource DropShadow}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```